# React Countdown Timer Padding Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

I have a working countdown timer & have added an if statement to address adding a preceding zero to hours, minutes, and seconds when less than 10; however, single digits are still showing up without the padding.
Can you please let me know what I did wrong with my if statement or use of this.state?

```
import React,{Component} from "react";

class Countdown extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
            this.state={
            hours:"00",
            minutes:"00",
            seconds:"00"
           }   
        }

        componentDidMount(){
            let countDownDate = new Date();
             countDownDate.setHours(24,0,0,0);
           
             setInterval(
                function () {
                  let now = new Date().getTime();
                  let timeleft = countDownDate - now;
                  this.setState({
                    hours: Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)),
                    minutes: Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)),
                    seconds: Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)
                  });
                }.bind(this), // we added the binding here
                1000
              );

                      
          if (this.state.hours < 10) {
            this.state.hours = "0"+this.state.hours;
        }
                  if (this.state.minutes < 10) {
            this.state.minutes = "0"+this.state.minutes;
          }
                  if (this.state.seconds < 10) {
            this.state.seconds = "0"+this.state.seconds;
        }
        }
   
         render(){    
    return (
        <>
        <div className="countdown-timer">
        <div className = "countdown-text">
          <p>DEAL ENDS<br></br> Hrs: Min: Sec:</p>
        </div>
        <div className="countdown-time">
        <p>{this.state.hours}:{this.state.minutes}:{this.state.seconds} </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
        )
        }
    
}

export default Countdown;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add if statements. Just check the conditions in your JSX expression itself like this: `<p>{this.state.hours < 10 ? "0" + this.state.hours : this.state.hours} : {this.state.minutes < 10 ? "0" + this.state.minutes : this.state.minutes : {this.state.seconds < 10 ? "0" + this.state.seconds : this.state.seconds}</p>`. It should work, tested. [Link to working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-meninsky-srd0kb?file=/src/App.js)

Your resulting code below:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Countdown extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hours: "00",
      minutes: "00",
      seconds: "00"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let countDownDate = new Date();
    countDownDate.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0);

    setInterval(
      function () {
        let now = new Date().getTime();
        let timeleft = countDownDate - now;
        this.setState({
          hours: Math.floor(
            (timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
          ),
          minutes: Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)),
          seconds: Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)
        });
      }.bind(this), // we added the binding here
      1000
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="countdown-timer">
          <div className="countdown-text">
            <p>
              DEAL ENDS<br></br> Hrs: Min: Sec:
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="countdown-time">
            <p>
              {this.state.hours < 10
                ? "0" + this.state.hours
                : this.state.hours}
              :
              {this.state.minutes < 10
                ? "0" + this.state.minutes
                : this.state.minutes}
              :
              {this.state.seconds < 10
                ? "0" + this.state.seconds
                : this.state.seconds}{" "}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Countdown;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the value of state directly, this will not re render the react component, you should change the state value using this.setState only, below you will find the modified code, which you can check.

```
    import React,{Component} from "react";

class Countdown extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
            this.state={
            hours:"00",
            minutes:"00",
            seconds:"00"
           }   
        }

        componentDidMount(){
            let countDownDate = new Date();
             countDownDate.setHours(24,13,0,0);
           
             setInterval(
                function () {
                  let now = new Date().getTime();
                  let timeleft = countDownDate - now;
                  const hour = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                  const minutes = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                  const seconds = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
                  this.setState({
                    hours: hour >= 10 ? hour : "0" + hour,
                    minutes: minutes >= 10 ? minutes : "0" + minutes,
                    seconds: seconds >= 10 ? seconds : "0" + seconds,
                  });
                }.bind(this), // we added the binding here
                1000
              );

                      
        }
   
         render(){    
    return (
        <>
        <div className="countdown-timer">
        <div className = "countdown-text">
          <p>DEAL ENDS<br></br> Hrs: Min: Sec:</p>
        </div>
        <div className="countdown-time">
        <p>{this.state.hours}:{this.state.minutes}:{this.state.seconds} </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
        )
        }
    
}

export default Countdown;
```